# Setting UIView tags with int values but not get the same tag value back

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIView` that are menuiitems and these menu items are dynamically created where i stamp each uiview tag by increment of 1, but when i want to retrieve the uiview tag values when the user clicks on the menu item i get a different tag number.

I want to retrieve the tag which has the id stored so that i can post that id to a php script.

How do i retrieve the tags form when i set them?

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIView *tempView = recognizer.view;
    NSNumber *tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempView.tag];
    int idCat = [tag intValue];
    NSLog(@"TAG %d", idCat);

    NSURLRequest *request =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/SubCategories.php?categoryid=%d", idCat]]];

    int i = 0;

    NSError *e;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&e];
    NSArray *arrCategoryList =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&e];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIView *uiView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [uiView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];
    [uiView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    viewController.view = uiView;

    UITableView *uiTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    [uiTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [uiView addSubview:uiTableView];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is the code that creates the menu items in another view:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/categories.php"]];

int i = 0;

NSError *e;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&e];
NSArray *arrCategoryList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&e];
for(NSDictionary *dictCategory in arrCategoryList)
{
    NSString *strCategoryId = [dictCategory objectForKey:@"CategoryId"];
    NSString *strCategoryName = [dictCategory objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"%@ : %@",strCategoryId,strCategoryName);

    UIView *linkMenu = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [linkMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(10, i+1, 300, 35)];
    linkMenu.tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", strCategoryId];
    linkMenu.layer.zPosition = 1;
    [viewSlide3 addSubview:linkMenu];
    [linkMenu setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    linkMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.9];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [linkMenu addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    UILabel *labelMenu = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [labelMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 300, 35)];
    [labelMenu setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
    [labelMenu setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [linkMenu addSubview:labelMenu];
    [labelMenu setText:strCategoryName];
    i = i + 35 + 1;
}
```

Comment: Are these views placed simply on the controller.view or are they a part of a UIScrollView or some other custom or addition UIView?

Comment: they are place inside another UIview

Comment: `sendSynchronousRequest` could freeze ui... Give a look at AFNetworking...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UIView` lets say A inside which are placed all the other menu items which are also `UIViews` lets say B, C, and D then most probably the recognizer.view is returning you A no matter which of the B, C, or D are pressed.

Write this in your `handleSingleTap` function:

```
CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
for(UIView * subView in myView ) //here myView should be the superView A where you have added all the menu item view B, C, and D
{
  if(CGRectContainsPoint(subView.bounds, touchPoint))
  {
    NSNumber *tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:subView.tag];
  }
}
```

That tag variable will have your final tag that you need.

Comment: I get this error:  -[UIView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2325b0
2014-04-23 19:12:10.932 whfc[31731:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2325b0'

Comment: has seemed to stop error happening but still the tag comes back with another value is there another way i can append the id to the uiview somehow

Comment: Please share your code where you are making the subviews and assigning the tags. That will make things clear

Comment: Also tell if the tag is still returning 0 or is now returning different values

Comment: The tag is returning a long value all the time

Comment: You are assigning the same tag to all the UIViews in this line
 `linkMenu.tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", strCategoryId];`
unless you are incrementing strCategoryId and setting this value again in the `NSUserDefaults`